# DIY portable solar panel mount

Tags: diy, photovoltaics, solar

So I just bought one of the [28W Big Blue portable solar panels](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EXWCPLC/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s04?ie=UTF8&psc=1) on Amazon and got myself a cheap camera tripod from a local garage sale, all for an upcoming camping trip. I want to use the tripod to create a simple, portable, adjustable solar mount that is collapsible.

My idea is to make a small square base that can screw into the top of the camera stand and use some kind of telescoping rods to create horizontal spans to hold the panel rigidly open (it measures about 33" x 11" when fully open and has 5 folding sections).

Now, I'm trying to think of something off the shelf that I could get/make/adapt/hack to use for the telescoping rod. Ideally, it would be something lightweight that is easy to extend and retract for easy carrying with the tripod. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What about a set of "rabbit ears" from an old TV or TV antenna? With two sets you should be able to use them to prop the panel, depending on how heavy it is and how substantial the antennas are. They typically have a screw-in base so you could remove them from their current mount and rig something up. Given how common these once were, you should be able to pick them up second-hand (or you might even have some in your house now!).

[image: TV with rabbit ears]